# Subsetting Dataset based on two condition, Save each dataframe into a .csv file, Iterate through each file and Plot figures

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am new to data science and I need help doing the following:

(I)  splitting a dataset based on unique groups in column and another group, in my case `region` and `country`

(II) I will like to save each dataframe as a .csv file- something like this `regionname_country.csv`, for example, `west_GER.csv`, `east_POL.csv`

(III) if possible, I will like to iterate `for loop`  through each .csv file to plot a scatterplot of `education vs age` for each df.

(IV)   Lastly save my plots/figures in a pdf file (4 figures per page)

```
'df'
   Region, country, Age, Education, Income, FICO, Target
1   west, GER, 43, 1, 47510, 710, 1
2   east, POL, 32, 2, 73640, 723, 1
3   east, POL, 22, 2, 88525, 610, 0
4   west, GER, 55, 0, 31008, 592, 0
5   north, USA, 19, 0, 18007, 599, 1
6   south, PER, 27, 2, 68850, 690, 0
7   south, BRZ, 56, 3, 71065, 592, 0
8   north, USA, 39, 1, 98004, 729, 1
9   east, JPN, 36, 2, 51361, 692, 0
10  west, ESP, 59, 1, 98643, 729, 1
```

Desired outcome:

```
 # df_to_csv : 'west_GER.csv'
west, GER, 43, 1, 47510, 710, 1 
west, GER, 55, 0, 31008, 592, 0
```

```
# west_ESP.csv
west, ESP, 59, 1, 98643, 729, 1
```

```
# east_POL.csv
east, POL, 32, 2, 73640, 723, 1
```

```
.
.
.
```

```
# north_USA.csv
north, USA, 39, 1, 98004, 729, 1  
north, USA, 19, 0, 18007, 599, 1
```

See below for my code

```
# using pandas 

# code for (I) and (II) not sure of my code but I think I need to nest through the for loop

for i, split_df in df.groupby('Region'):
     for j in df.groupby('country'): # not sure of the nested for loop
      split_df.to_csv(f'{i,j}.csv', index = False) # not sure of the {i,j} part

# code for (III) and (IV)

import glob
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plot
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages


filenames = sorted(glob.glob('_*.csv')) # retrieving all files containing '_' since we have region_country.csv
filenames = filenames[0:len(filenames)]
for filename in filenames:
    print(filename)

    data = numpy.loadtxt(fname=filename, delimiter=',')
    # The PDF document
    pdf_pages = PdfPages('plots.pdf')
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()    # create a figure

    # Generate the pages
    nb_plots = data.shape[0]
    nb_plots_per_page = 4
    nb_pages = int(numpy.ceil(nb_plots / float(nb_plots_per_page)))
    grid_size = (nb_plots_per_page, 1)
    for i, samples in enumerate(data):
    # Create a figure instance (ie. a new page) if needed
      if i % nb_plots_per_page == 0:
      fig = plot.figure(figsize=(8.5, 12), dpi=125)

    # plot stuff 
      x = data[:,2]  # age column
      y = data[:,3] # education column

     ax.plot(x, y,color = colorlist[i])

     ax.set_xscale("log")
     ax.set_xlabel("x")
     ax.set_ylabel("y")

     plt.show()
    # Close the page if needed
    if (i + 1) % nb_plots_per_page == 0 or (i + 1) == nb_plots:
    plot.tight_layout()
    pdf_pages.savefig(fig)
 
    # Write the PDF document to the disk
    pdf_pages.close()
```

Any assistance will be much appreciated, I am open to both python and R. Thank you in advance.

````
#Attempt for PCA 


import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for ax, file in zip(axs.flatten(), glob.glob("./*csv")):
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(file) # read each csv file
    df_temp.drop('Unnamed: 0', axis=1, inplace=True) # drop the index number columns
    df_temp = df_temp.dropna() # drop NaNs

    X = df_temp.iloc[:,4:len(df_temp.columns)]#.astype(float) # select the 5th columns to the end 
    y = df_temp.iloc[:,0] # the first column is the label column
    # PCA starts from here
    scaler = StandardScaler()
    scaler.fit(X)
    X = scaler.transform(X)
    pca = PCA(n_components=2)
    pca.fit(X)
    x_pca = pca.transform(X)
     # I want to convert the x_pca array in dataframe for easier plotting
    data = pd.DataFrame({'PC1': x_pca[:, 0], 'PC2': x_pca[:, 1]})
    PC1_temp = data['PC1'][0]
    PC2_temp = data['PC2'][0]
    categories = y # label column to be used for distinguish the two classes
    colormap = np.array(['r', 'g']) # desired color red and green for the two distinct classes in the label column
    ax.scatter(x_pca[:,0], x_pca[,:1],c=colormap[categories])
    ax.set_title(f"PC1:{PC1_temp}, P2:{PC2_temp}")
    ax.set_xlabel("PC1")
    ax.set_ylabel("PC2")
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.legend()# Also, I want to include a legend to show the 'r', 'g' values of the two distinct classes of label column
fig.savefig("scatter.pdf")

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Python:
(I) & (II):

```
for i in df.groupby(["Region", "country"])[["Region", "country"]].apply(lambda x: list(np.unique(x))):
    df.groupby(["Region", "country"]).get_group((i[1], i[0])).to_csv(f"{i[1]}_{i[0]}.csv")
```

(III) & (IV):

```
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=2)
for ax, file in zip(axs.flatten(), glob.glob("./*csv")):
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(file)
    region_temp = df_temp['Region'][0]
    country_temp = df_temp['country'][0]    
    ax.scatter(df_temp["Age"], df_temp["Education"])
    ax.set_title(f"Region:{region_temp}, Country:{country_temp}")
    ax.set_xlabel("Age")
    ax.set_ylabel("Education")
    plt.tight_layout()
fig.savefig("scatter.pdf")
```

Comment: @Andre.S. Thanks for this, code III and IV works perfectly well, however,  your code (I and II), returns  one unique region per country for each .csv file (I think I didn't explain this part correctly). What I desire is some thing like this: `west_UK.csv`,  `west_ESP.csv`, `north_USA.csv`, `east_POL.csv` and `east_JPN.csv`. Note that both UK and ESP both belong to west region and . in simpler terms, each .csv should have unique country within a unique region. Thanks

Comment: I just updated the solution for (I) & (II). Upvotes are welcome if it helps you :)

Comment: @Andre.S.  Unfortunately, it didn't work, it returned only 1 .csv file out of 40 files.

Comment: Mhh, the code for (I) and (II) applied to the above DataFrame generates 7 separate CSVs. Did you maybe forget the "f" in the string of the `.to_csv` argument? Then the CSV would be overwritten with every iteration.

Comment: @Andre.S. Thanks it works fine now! One last thing, assuming in code (III and IV) I want to do  PCA with `age` `income`, `Education` and `FICO` (numeric features) columns, thereby plotting PC1 v PC2 for each csv file. At what point do I include the normalize and pca.fit step (if you could include it and comment  in your answer code, I would really appreciate it!) Thanks you are a lifesaver!

Comment: You can use `df_temp` in the loop for your normalization and PCA calculation.

Comment: @Andre.S. Please can you take a look at my 'Attempt for PCA' in my original post. I want to plot the PC1 vs PC2. I tried replicating your initial code, but I couldn't figure it out. Please can you comment the steps so I can understand the rationale behind each step.  You can respond below your initial post. Thanks alot!  See the link i am using for my PCA:  https://datascienceplus.com/principal-component-analysis-pca-with-python/

Comment: Actually your solution looks quite good. Where exact do you struggle? Applied to your example data it crashed as you have not enough samples (e.g. only 1 for east_JPN).

Comment: So the graph layout  (2 by 2) is rendering but the actual scatterplot is not displaying. Also, I am getting 'ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

Answer (score 0):

In R, you can do this as :

```
library(tidyverse)

#get data in list of dataframes
df %>%
  select(Region, country, Education, Age) %>%
  group_split(Region, country) -> split_data

#From list of data create list of plots. 
list_plots <- map(split_data, ~ggplot(.) + aes(Education, Age) + 
                geom_point() + 
                 ggtitle(sprintf('Plot for region %s and country %s', 
                 first(.$Region), first(.$country))))

#Write the plots in pdf as well as write the csvs.
pdf("plots.pdf", onefile = TRUE)
for (i in seq_along(list_plots)) {
  write.csv(split_data, sprintf('%s_%s.csv', 
      split_data[[i]]$Region[1], split_data[[i]]$country[1]), row.names = FALSE)
  print(list_plots[[i]]) 
}
dev.off()
```

Comment: `@Ronak`, the plots worked (with the exception that I want 4 figures per page instead of 1 figure per page). Also each of the `.csv` file returns  40 rows of `<tbl_df[,140]>` . I think this is because you plotted the figures before exporting the subset data frames (I am not sure though).  Please can you subset the dataset based on the unique region & unique country combination you used, also, can you make it 4 figures  per page. Thanks in advance